# Can't set response header as application/json

Tags: json, rest

My request's header is application/json but my response's header is application/xml. How can I change my response header to application/json?

Request Header:

> ```
> "Accept-Encoding" = gzip;
> "Content-Length" = 21;
> "Content-Type" = "application/json";
> "User-Agent" = "BarcodeReader 1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iPhone OS 7.0.3; en_US)";
> ```

Response Header:

> ```
> "Cache-Control" = private;
> Connection = close;
> "Content-Length" = 689;
> "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
> Date = "Mon, 09 Dec 2013 06:45:32 GMT";
> Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
> "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
> "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
> ```

The code:

```
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wcftest.amerikanhastanesi.org/BarkodIOS.svc/rest/HastaAra"]];
    NSData *myPostData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"protokolNo\":%d}",protokolNo] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData *myMutablePostData = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithData:myPostData];

    [request setPostBody:myMutablePostData];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSLog(@"%@",[request responseHeaders]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[request requestHeaders]);

     id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[request responseString]
     dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
     error:nil ];
    HastaModel *h;
    for(NSDictionary *theItem in [jsonObjects objectForKey:@"HastaAraResult"]){
        h = [[HastaModel alloc]initWithDictionary: theItem];

    }

    return h;
```

Please don't ask me to use ASIFormData instead of using ASIHTTPRequest. Thank you.

Comment: What is responding? It's not related to iOS or objective-c. The web server has to add the Content-Type header to the response.

Comment: I modified MIME but didn't work. Then I add [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
         to cs and it didn't work also. So I think it's the code problem.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the code you are using to generate the HTTP response (and specifically the header for that response).

Comment: The response header is set by the server which is responding. If you want the response to be json instead of xml, then you need to determine how to change the request so that the responding server sends json.

Comment: How can I do it? I did add [WebInvoke(Method="POST"),RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.JSON,ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.JSON,UriTemplate = "sada"]

Answer (score 0):

If is a real REST Full implemented you can use the header parameter : Accept: application/json

Comment: How can I understand that? I add the rest endpoint to the wcf.